# Conditional Formatting for 100% does not work

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

What if I want to colour the cells without using the icon sets for percentages? I have a very complex formula built in a cell:

```
=IF($C4="Not Defined","Not Defined",IF(COUNTIFS('Data INC (Q1+04+05._2016)'!$Q:$Q,$B4,'Data INC (Q1+04+05._2016)'!$G:$G,I$3,'Data INC (Q1+04+05._2016)'!$AP:$AP,$I$1)=0,"No incidents",CONCATENATE(IFERROR((TEXT(ROUNDUP(((COUNTIFS('Data INC (Q1+04+05._2016)'!$Q:$Q,$B4,'Data INC (Q1+04+05._2016)'!$G:$G,I$3,'Data INC (Q1+04+05._2016)'!$AP:$AP,$I$1,'Data INC (Q1+04+05._2016)'!$AV:$AV,TRUE))/(COUNTIFS('Data INC (Q1+04+05._2016)'!$Q:$Q,$B4,'Data INC (Q1+04+05._2016)'!$G:$G,I$3,'Data INC (Q1+04+05._2016)'!$AP:$AP,$I$1))),2),"0.00%")),""))))
```

For this, I have a 3 criteria conditional formatting: between 0 and 0.75 percentages turn to red between 0.75 and 0.95 percentages turn to yellow between 0.95 to 1 percentages turn to green

The conditional formatting for 100% does not work, it turns to red. The conditional formatting only works if I skip the percentage from the formula and turns the value between 0 and 1. I tried the cell format to number, percentage, general, custom and does not work.

Comment: Colour the cells? What cells? Are you referring to Excel? Or Google Sheets? Or what?

Comment: Excel 2010. Cells with values. The values are calculated from the above formula I use in the cells of Excel.

Comment: Are you checking whether the cell equals 1 or 100?  It should be 1 for 100%.

Comment: Without trying to convert the value to percentage, the conditional formatting is working with the range from 0 - 1, with the red, yellow and green - even for the 100%.
Every case I try to convert the value to percentage, the green part of the conditional formatting is corrupted.

Comment: The main problem is that if I get the value in the range 0-1, I cannot modify the number format to percentage.
So I tried to incorporate some converting to the big formula, but then the conditional formatting does not work for the 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes your formula is returning a correct value.

Your conditional formatting is testing for a numeric value.  Your formula is returning a text string.  And your description of how you have set up your conditional formatting is not clear.

- Remove the `TEXT` function from your formula so it returns a numeric value.
- Format the cell to percent with two decimal places.
- If the conditional formatting still does not work, describe exactly how you have it set up, using the terms in the dialog boxes, and exactly what is contained there (or screen shots if you can).

Comment: TEXT function from the formula is removed.
Number formatting the cells to percent does not work.
The conditional formatting set up I use:

Comment: If you are unable to format the cells, then your formula is not returning a number (or you are not formatting the cells correctly).  What does the following return `=ISTEXT(cell containing your formula)`?  (eg:  =ISTEXT(A1)` where `A1` contains your formula)

Comment: @llidi It may also be the case that your `CONCATENATE` function is converting things to text.  I'm not really sure what you are doing with that function.

Comment: Hello Ron. Yes, that was the problem, the CONCATENATE function transformed the values to text so that's why I could not format the values as numbers.
I solved it with adding VALUE in front of CONCATENATE in the formula and it returned the results as numbers instead of texts. :)

Case is solved.

And many thanks :)

Comment: @llidi since it seemed to help you, if you could mark my response as the answer I would appreciate it.